# How to plot solutions of equation involving Bessel functions?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm new user in Mathematica and I'm trying to plot the solutions of this equation

$$
    G_{0}(r) = i\frac{H_{0}(kr)}{8k^2}-\frac{K_{0}(kr)}{4\pi k^2}
$$
where $H_{0}$ is the zeroth-order Hankel function and $K_{0}$ is the zeroth-order modified Bessel function of the second kind. $k$ is given by: k = $\sqrt{\omega}(\frac{\rho}{E})^{1/4}$, $\rho$ and $E$ constants. I tried to do this:

[image: I tried to do this]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
omega = 10;
rho = 1.123;
h = 0.1;
EY = 15;
k = Sqrt[omega] (rho/EY)^(0.25);
Go[r_, k_] := 
  Re[I (HankelH2[k, r]/(8 k^2) - BesselJ[k, r]/(4 Pi k^2))];

Plot[
 Go[r, .6], {r, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

You have many syntactic errors.  A function--which in your context means a function whose evaluation is delayed--is defined with := (not =).  Your `Go` function takes *two* arguments, not one.  Manipulate is for *changing* or *adjusting* some code, etc.  You cannot plot an imaginary function... and more.

The above may help you get started.

Comment: **"A function is defined with := (not =).":** This is a piece of bad advice that is thrown around far too widely and liberally. In reality, [immediate and delayed definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) are both very powerful and very different concepts, and it is worth any Mathematica programmer's time to study their differences in detail. tl;dr – both immediate and delayed functions are useful in their own way. If you know them both, more power to you as a programmer.

Comment: Thank you! This is helping me. I went behind the documentation to understand better about how the functions are defined :)